# How to add page header & footer to pdf using export plugin in grails?

Tags: grails, pdf, header, pdf-generation, footer

I am able to generate & download pdf file using **export plugin**. But, now **I want to add PAGE HEADER & FOOTER in the pdf**.

Can anybody please tell me how can I achieve that? Reference links are also ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin isn't designed to support these features, however, you can implement them if you want.

If you take a look at the default implementation for the [DefaultPDFExporter](https://github.com/gpc/grails-export/blob/master/src/groovy/de/andreasschmitt/export/exporter/DefaultPDFExporter.groovy) which is used by the plugin to render PDF documents you will see it does include a blank footer, but you can't configure the text. You will also see that it doesn't support adding in a header either. This means you are going to have to write your own PDF exporter implementation.

Since you want to generate a custom PDF document you will need to implement your own version of the `DefaultPDFExporter` which does support these features. You can do this by extending the `AbstractExporter` and using the `DefaultPDFExporter` as your guide. You will also need to configure your application to use your own implementation instead of the default. Take a look at the `doWithSpring` section of the [ExportGrailsPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/gpc/grails-export/blob/master/ExportGrailsPlugin.groovy) to see how your exporter bean should be defined in your `Resources.groovy`.

This isn't something that is exactly straight forward or easy. It does require you to have a good understanding of Grails, Spring, and Java.